# How to use multiple vhosts in a Spring RabbitMQ project?

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq-exchange, spring-rabbit

I've the following two **Configuration** classes:

```
@Configuration
@EnableRabbit
@Import({ LocalRabbitConfigA.class, CloudRabbitConfigA.class })
public class RabbitConfigA {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("rabbitConnectionFactory_A")
    private ConnectionFactory rabbitConnectionFactory;

    @Bean(name = "admin_A")
    AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin() {
        return new RabbitAdmin(rabbitConnectionFactory);
    }

    @Bean(name = "Exchange_A")
    DirectExchange receiverExchange() {
        return new DirectExchange("Exchange_A", true, false);
    }
}
```

And

```
@Configuration
@EnableRabbit
@Import({ LocalRabbitConfigB.class, CloudRabbitConfigB.class })
public class RabbitConfigB {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("rabbitConnectionFactory_B")
    private ConnectionFactory rabbitConnectionFactory;

    @Bean(name = "admin_B")
    AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin() {
        return new RabbitAdmin(rabbitConnectionFactory);
    }

    @Bean(name = "Exchange_B")
    DirectExchange receiverExchange() {
        return new DirectExchange("Exchange_B", true, false);
    }
}
```

Note that the LocalRabbitConfigA and LocalRabbitConfigB classes define the connectionFactory which connects to a different VHost.

When starting the application (within Tomcat), all the Exchanges are created in **both** VHosts.

The question is how to define that a certain Exchange/Queue is created by a specific ConnectionFactiory ?

So that VHost A contains only the Exchange_A, and VHost B only Exchange_B ?

Comment: would you mind sharing the full code for the configuration classes. I'm trying to implement such a scenario where i have two vhosts and i have been stuck.

Comment: @martinkimani Sorry, I cannot access the code anymore...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [conditional declaration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/#conditional-declaration).

Specifically:

```
@Bean(name = "Exchange_B")
DirectExchange receiverExchange() {
    DirectExchange exchange = new DirectExchange("Exchange_B", true, false);
    exchange.setAdminsThatShouldDeclare(amqpAdmin());
    return exchange;
}
```

Comment: I just found this also, but didn't dare to answer my question so quickly... But anyhow, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve this using SimpleRoutingConnectionFactory, where we create multiple connection factories each for a vhost and configure it to SimpleRoutingConnectionFactory.

From the spring documentation: [spring doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.3.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/amqp.html#routing-connection-factory)

```
public class MyService {

    @Autowired
    private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    public void service(String vHost, String payload) {
        SimpleResourceHolder.bind(rabbitTemplate.getConnectionFactory(), vHost);
        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(payload);
        SimpleResourceHolder.unbind(rabbitTemplate.getConnectionFactory());
    }

}
```

I have created a git repo showing how to do this: [spring-boot-amqp-multiple-vhosts](https://github.com/ledwinson/spring-boot-amqp-multiple-vhosts)

Comment: I could probably put the `SimpleResourceHolder.bind(?,?)` within a `OncePerRequestFilter` right?